# Inserting session user data in php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

**---------------START-UPDATE-----------------**

*I added the session in the code and did not logout then login to refresh the variable .. my bad, thanks guy.*

**---------------END-UPDATE-----------------**

I am using Codeigniter 3.0, I can read the session data, I have tested this by a echo. however when i try to insert into the table I get this error.

**Error**

```
  Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'LoginID' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `Report_Comments` (`Comments`, `ReportID`, `LoginID`) VALUES (',l;', '53', NULL)

Filename: models/report/Report_model.php

Line Number: 58
```

**Code (Model)**

```
function create_comment()
    {
        $new_comment = array(
            'Comments' => $this->input->post('Comments'),
            'ReportID' => $this->input->post('ReportID'),
            'UserID' => $this->session->userdata('LoginID')
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('Report_Comments', $new_comment);
        return $insert;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `LoginId` field in your `Report_Comments` table ?

Comment: Yeah, because here you have 
`'UserID' => $this->session->userdata('LoginID')` instead of `LoginID`

Comment: Hmm the session data is set to LoginID, the column in the table is UserID

Comment: @Beep, It looks like you are getting a NULL from the session data.

Comment: If your column name is really `UserID` then it cant be fail.

Comment: @DFriend, When I echo out the LoginID in a view I get the id, however in the model im  not sure

Comment: @HendraNucleo I know thats what im thinking, but as Dfriend pointed out the session variable reads null

Comment: Hmm Update... for some strange reason It has decided to work

Comment: Hard to fix if it works. ha ha.  Could be the session timed out. I'm going to provide an answer that will help catch missing input problems.

Comment: Ok np. and yes lol. it was because i did not logout then login lol

Comment: Get some beers LMAO :D

Comment: I'm up for a beer too!

Comment: It would be a really good idea to make sure the user is logged in somewhere early in the controller that calls this model/method

Comment: Anyway, when it will come to 4? just curious if any progress ?

Comment: The user was logged in, but the new session variable was not present upon login so it did not catch it. but yes good point.

Comment: All working well, always was lol. thanks for the check code @DFriend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a good idea to double check that you have values assigned to variables before you use them. This revised model function provides some checking.

```
  function create_comment()
  {
    $comments = $this->input->post('Comments');
    $reportID = $this->input->post('ReportID');
    $userID = $this->session->userdata('LoginID');
    if(isset($reportID) && isset($userID))
    {
      $new_comment = array(
          'Comments' => isset($comments) ? $comments : "",
          'ReportID' => $reportID,
          'UserID' => $userID
      );
      return $this->db->insert('Report_Comments', $new_comment);
    }
    return FALSE;
  }
```

The above operates with the idea that the insert should not be attempted unless the `ReportID` and `UserID` values are set with some value. If no comments are present then an empty string will be save to the db.

Comment: Nice tip, thanks dude, question the return false could i return a alert box ?

Comment: I would recommend that the controller act on the return from the model. But yes, the controller could provide some feedback on the failure to save the comment.